# Manipulate a Differential Equation result

Tags: plotting, manipulate, differential-equations

I want to Manipulate the result of Differential Equation like :

```
F[x_] = y[x] /. First@DSolve[x - y'[x] + y''[x] == 0, y[x], x]
Manipulate[Plot[F[x], {x, -10, 10}], {C[1], 1, 6}, {C[2], -2, 5}]
```

the result of the equation is :

```
x + x^2/2 + E^x C[1] + C[2]
```

but I don't get any Curve on the display.

[image]

Comment: This will work : `Manipulate[
 Plot[F[x] /. {C[1] -> a, C[2] -> b}, {x, -10, 10}], {a, 1, 
  6}, {b, -2, 5}]`

Comment: @b.gatessucks , Could you tell me what is `C[1]->a` Called?
I want to search it in help.

Comment: Why do you guys so often answer in comments instead of an answer? *b.gatessucks*'s answer may be brief, but at least 4 users found it useful in only 9 minutes time.

Comment: `->` is the operator form of [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html). When used in conjunction with [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`/.`) (or an of the replace functions), the left-hand side (LHS) of the `Rule` is transformed into the right-hand side. Compare this to  [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html) (`:>`).

Comment: @stevenvh effort. Sometimes it is just easier to post a hint in a comment, then have to explain things in an answer. So, just laziness.

Comment: @rcollyer - Ah, in that case I take back everything I said. Laziness is a Good Excuse. :-)

Comment: @stevenvh the fundamental working principal of a software engineer. Boss: "Why did you spend 3 weeks automating a 10 minute job?" SWE: "So, I wouldn't have to do it ever again." I've spent a _lot_ of time automating such tasks. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many fixes to this issue. I would recommend formulating problem from the start in terms of your constants. So you know exactly what constants mean.

```
F[x_, a_, b_] = y[x] 
            /. First@ DSolve[{x - y'[x] + y''[x] == 0, y[0] == a, y'[0] == b}, y[x], x];

Manipulate[Plot[F[x, a, b], {x, -10, 10}, PlotLabel -> F[x, a, b]], 
  {{a, -4, "initial function"}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{b, .96, "initial 1st derivative"}, .5, 1.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

For your more complicated case mentioned in the comments do this:

```
G[x_, a_, b_, c_] = {y[x], z[x]} /. First@DSolve[{y'[x] - 8*z'[x] == x^2, 
  z''[x] == x - y[x], y[0] == a, y'[0] == b, z[0] == c}, {y[x], z[x]}, x] // FullSimplify;

G[x, a, b, c] // Column // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate@G[x, a, b, c], {x, -5, 5}, Filling -> 0, 
PlotLabel -> Column[G[x, a, b, c]]], 
{{a, 8, "initial y"}, -10, 10,Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{b, 0, "initial y'"}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{c, 0, "initial z"}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I have another question what should I do when I have more complex equation like this :

`F[x_] = y[x] /. 
  First@DSolve[{y'[x] - 8*z'[x] == x^2, z''[x] == x - y[x]}, {y[x], 
     z[x]}, x];
G[x_] = z[x] /. 
  First@DSolve[{y'[x] - 8*z'[x] == x^2, z''[x] == x - y[x]}, {y[x], 
     z[x]}, x]`

I want to manipulate both of them at the same time , like this :

`Manipulate[
 Plot[{F[x] /. {C[1] -> a, C[2] -> b}, 
   G[x] /. {C[1] -> a, C[2] -> a}}, {x, -10, 10}], {a, -10, 
  10}, {b, -10, 10}]`

still I have the same problem like above.

Comment: `G[x]` and `F[x]` contain another constant, `C[3]`, so you need to set that to some value if  you want to Plot them: `Manipulate[Plot[{F[x], G[x]} /. {C[1] -> a, C[2] -> b, C[3]-> c}, {x, -10, 10}], {a, -10, 10}, {b, -10, 10}, {c, -10, 10}]`. You can always look at the results of your assignments to check the generated constants.

Comment: @DSaad you just have to do the same thing for all functions and constants that you use. BTW the code that you show in the comment is different from my implementation. It's b.gatessucks version . My version is different. I am kind of not sure if you understood my answer in the 1st place ;-)

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I understand your version but I don't how to find the a and b and c.

Comment: @DSaad I updated the answer

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Thank you.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Can I ask you something , It's more mathematics question , How do you find out that 
`y[0] == a, y'[0] == b, z[0] == c` ?
I mean how do you find with equation would be `C[1]` or `C[2]` or `C[3]`?

Answer (score 0):

For a simple fix, does this behave as expected?

```
With[{fx = F[x]},
  Manipulate[Plot[fx, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All], {C[1], 1, 6}, {C[2], -2, 5000}]
]
```

I changed the range of `C[2]` so that its effect would be noticeable.

I'd still choose Vitaliy's method I think.